# Temporary Accounts on Paypal or other payment solution

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I'm looking to create temporary accounts that can accept money & perform payments.

I want it to be automatically so probably I will need to use some API, Maybe PAyPal API...

Can I do it via Paypal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Paypal doesnt give temprary accounts. Even to test your application you need two actual accounts. Except in case of sandbox.

Regarding your need of creating account via api, you need to haveseparate accounts.
Either you can use paypal and create su merchant, this need very high security.
Or you can locate services like bancbox , i am sure there are similar services out there to use banking and financial connections. but bancbox is a good choice to begun with.

You can
1. Search for paypal addaptive accounts
2.  bancbox.com